# Scrapy view returns a blank page

Tags: python, web-scraping, web-crawler, scrapy

I'm new at Scrapy and I was just trying to scrape http://www.diseasesdatabase.com/

When I type `scrapy view http://www.diseasesdatabase.com/`, it displays a blank page but if I download the page and do it on the local file, it displays as usual. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretend being a real browser providing a `User-Agent` header:

```
scrapy view http://www.diseasesdatabase.com/ -s USER_AGENT="Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.130 Safari/537.36"
```

Worked for me.

Note that `-s` option here helps to override the built-in [`USER_AGENT` setting](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#user-agent).

Comment: All well and good but I would still like to know why it returns a blank page

Comment: +1. Just that I think **scrapy** should really put this as a remark first page in their docs. Just that how many people have fallen into this and asked this similar question haha.

Comment: @RahulSarma because this sites checks the User-Agent header as, most likely, an anti-web-scraping technique.

Comment: @RahulSarma also see http://www.mrtablet.demon.co.uk/diseases_database_acceptable_use_policy.htm text describing what they do to defend themselves.

Comment: @alecxe That makes sense. Not specific to this particular website or question, but where is the code that checks the User-Agent header normally located? In script files or somewhere else?

Comment: @RahulSarma well, you can define the `USER_AGENT` setting once in your `settings.py`. You can also use a middleware to dynamically set this header. For example, there is a simple one I've written that for each request randomly sets the user-agent based on the real-world browser usage statistics, check it out: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scrapy-fake-useragent

Comment: Thanks but what I meant was that where do the website devs include the code that checks for web-scrapers? In script files?

Comment: @RahulSarma okay, it depends, there are special services that work against web scrapers, e.g. http://scrapedefender.com/. There could be custom tools used. We cannot know it for sure. It is a black box.