# Scrapy getting blank pages of javascript

Tags: javascript, python, django, scrapy

When attempting to use scrapy to view or scrape http://www.kw.com/kw/agent/johndoucette (or most pages on that domain), I get back a blank page.  Viewing the page source returns a mess of hidden javascript, but that's about it.

I've tried many different user agents, proxies, no proxies, settings, etc. (e.g. `scrapy view http://www.kw.com/kw/agent/johndoucette -s USER_AGENT="Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/4302357130 Safari/537.36"` from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31189588/scrapy-view-returns-a-blank-page))  It's not my settings - it's reproducible from the scrapy shell view(response) command on a new install.  I just don't know how to ignore that script.

Is there any way to get around this?

Answer (score 1):

You're getting this because the website is served up via "Incapsula", which uses a Javascript test before allowing you to continue onto the page.  Since Scrapy doesn't process Javascript, you aren't getting any further then that.

To see what's going on, open up Chrome, go to Privacy, and disable cookies and Javascript.

The site is actively trying to block Crawling, which is a clear indication that they don't want to be crawled.

Comment: So it's not a need to skip over the javascript, but a need to interact with it?  It seems odd - for all of the major websites that clearly wish not to be crawled or indexed, this seems like a pretty simple workaround.

Comment: It could be that, or it could be things like a combination of browser features reported vs. those that *should* be there.  It could be how it's sending headers.  It could be a lot of things, because I truthfully am not that familiar with Incapsula.