# Scrapy gets totally different HTML than what browser shows as source HTML

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, scrapy, python-requests

I have been doing web scraping for a few months and am trying to level up. Recently I started working with scrapy. I came across a site that has me stumped: https://www.comperdelivery.com.br/bebidas-3/c. I've been unable to get the page as loaded in-browser with neither scrapy nor requests.

I have tried a few different code snippets, but essentially I am working with these commands in my terminal:

```
scrapy shell https://www.comperdelivery.com.br/bebidas-3/c
>>> response.body
```

`response.body` is completely different than what I see in Firefox or Chrome, not even having the same `body` tag. I have tried specifying a proper user agent like this to no avail, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31189654/9450453):

```
scrapy shell https://www.comperdelivery.com.br/bebidas-3/c -s USER_AGENT="Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.130 Safari/537.36"
```

I understand that there is probably something going on in the site's server that I don't understand. Who here can enlighten me?

Comment: I checked it using scrapy and it's the same. You would probably inspect the page using firefox and chrome. Note that the page is using javascript to populate some elements and change some that's why it looks different when you inspect it but if you right click and view the page source then it will be the same.

Comment: @MohammedAbuIriban if I right click and view page source the resulting HTML is the same as what Firefox or Chrome developer tools show me. At the highest level, view page source gets `<body class="catalog type-categoria">` as its body tag, while scrapy gets `<body class="multistore">`. Any idea what I could be missing?

Comment: it seems that the website redirects to homepage if some of cookies are not presented. I was able to fetch the page using `requests` by setting the cookies that the website initialise after visiting the homepage. So the solution is to set a group of cookies and then scrape the page and you will get what you want.

Comment: Ok, fetching the page with requests by manually copying the cookies from my browser's developer tools works, but what if I wanted to automate this? The cookies expire after a time.